# for loop as predicate xquery, xpath

Tags: xml, loops, xpath, xquery, tei-publisher

I have a list of /bibl entries, each with a /date @when="YEAR" child element. I am trying to output only the first instance of each year.

```
`<listBibl>
            <bibl>
                <date when="1746"/> 
            </bibl>
            <bibl>
                <date when="1746"/> 
            </bibl>
            <bibl>
                <date when="1746"/> 
            </bibl>
            <bibl>
                <date when="1746"/>
            </bibl>
          <bibl>
                <date when="1747"/> 
            </bibl>
            <bibl>
                <date when="1747"/>
            </bibl>
            <bibl>
                <date when="1747"/> 
            </bibl>
          <bibl>
                <date when="1754"/>
            </bibl>
            <bibl>
                <date when="1754"/>
            </bibl>
          </listBibl>
```

I have written an expression that finds this: `for $d in /date/@when return (/date[@when=$d])[1]` 
But this won’t work in the programme (teipublisher) I am using to output the attribute value. Does anybody have any suggestions about how I might do this differently.

Comment: XQuery FLWOR expression supports `group by` clause.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Hello, thank you I will try that, could you be very kind and show me how that would work I am quite new to XQuery

Comment: @noahjb in case Yitzhak's solution worked please accept that answer. Otherwise please let us know what is wrong with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using BaseX, v.9.6.4

**XQuery**

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare context item := document {
<listBibl>
    <bibl>
        <date when="1746"/>
    </bibl>
    <bibl>
        <date when="1746"/>
    </bibl>
    <bibl>
        <date when="1746"/>
    </bibl>
    <bibl>
        <date when="1746"/>
    </bibl>
    <bibl>
        <date when="1747"/>
    </bibl>
    <bibl>
        <date when="1747"/>
    </bibl>
    <bibl>
        <date when="1747"/>
    </bibl>
    <bibl>
        <date when="1754"/>
    </bibl>
    <bibl>
        <date when="1754"/>
    </bibl>
</listBibl>
};

<listBibl>
{
  for $x in ./listBibl/bibl
  let $date := $x/date/@when
  group by $date
  order by $date
  return <bibl>
        <date when="{$date}"/>
    </bibl>
}
</listBibl>
```

**Output XML**

```
<listBibl>
  <bibl>
    <date when="1746"/>
  </bibl>
  <bibl>
    <date when="1747"/>
  </bibl>
  <bibl>
    <date when="1754"/>
  </bibl>
</listBibl>
```